# JQuery Function Not Updating Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two hidden fields for business and home address. They are updated to "true" on the event that the content for the specific textboxes are changed. However, because there are various fields within the div, I used jquery to get all objects of type text within the div. Basically what I'm trying to do is check if the text has changed and then update a hidden field value on my ascx form to true.

```
InitAddressOnChange: function () {
    $('#divBusinessAddress input[type=text]').change(function () {
        $("[id$='hiddenBusinessField']").val("true");
    });

    $('#divHomeAddress input[type=text]').change(function () {
        $("[id$='hiddenBusinessField']").val("true");
    });
}
```

Here are my hidden fields:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID ="hiddenBusinessField" runat="server" value="false"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID ="hiddenHomeField" runat="server" value="false"/>
```

I tried debugging in the browser but I'm having an issue figuring this out. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I'm fairly new to JQuery.

Comment: jquery works on client machine and you are trying to set val of ASP code. What's the rendered HTML on client browser?

Comment: first check if the events are definitely firing. Just put something like `console.log("I'm here in event <x>");` inside the function of each event and see if you're definitely running them. then if that's happening, have a look at your HTML and see if `$("[id$='hiddenBusinessField']")` is the correct identifier for that field. ASP.NET's client-side IDs are not always the ones that you specify in the <asp: markup.